# Cannot find function stringify Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been trying to get a **Google App** Script together that works with Google's Directory API to update a large number of groups.

To my knowledge Google App Scripts uses javascript. I can't find a library to import or a `json.stringify` function to copy/paste into my code. Does anyone know of one?

I have the following code after the necessary authentication steps.

```
 var options = {
   'method' : 'Post',
   'contentType' : 'application/json',
   'followRedirects' : true,
   'muteHttpExceptions': true,
   'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()},        
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
 };


  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/" + groupkey + "/members";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Error Message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function stringify in object [object Object]. (line 219, file "Code")

Comment: You need to provide more details. In testing, I can stringify without any additional imports or similar.

`function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(new Date(2006, 0, 2, 15, 4, 5)));
  // '"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"'

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
  // '{"x":5,"y":6}'
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify([new Number(3), new String('false'), new Boolean(false)]));
  // '[3,"false",false]'
}`

Comment: What's the structure of `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.stringify() should "just work", there is no "import" or similar action required.

Based on your error message it looks like you have accidentally assigned an object to the identifier JSON elsewhere in your code, with something like  `JSON = {};`

Search for all instances of "JSON" in your code and see if you are incorrectly assigning it a value somewhere.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: I got the same error too and I found out that there is a JSON variable defined in my code. Thanks a lot!